# F# CsvProvider MissingMethodException

Tags: f#, f#-data, missingmethodexception

I am trying to create a F# command line tool to parse a CSV file and convert it to a gpx file. I am using the CsvProvider and get the following error when reading the CSV file:

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'FSharp.Data.Runtime.CsvFile`1<!0> FSharp.Data.Runtime.CsvFile`1.Create(System.Func`3<System.Object,System.String[],!0>, System.Func`2<!0,System.String[]>, System.IO.TextReader, System.String, System.Char, System.Boolean, System.Boolean, System.Int32, System.Boolean)'.'
```

The whole project can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/crehmann/Esp32GpsLogger/tree/master/tools/CsvToGpxConverter

I am using netcoreapp3.1 as target framework and FSharp.Data in version 3.3.3 and FSharp.Core in version 4.7.1

Any guidance on how I can get rid of this exception would be much appreciated!

Comment: I have the same issue with `GraphQLProvider` on Core 3.1 when F# Core is 4.7.1

Answer (score 0):

It seems to  be fixed with the latest F# Milestone 16.6. The resolved GitHub issue: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/8743
I have Visual F# Tools 10.9.1.0 for F# 4.7   16.6.0-beta.20217.4+1c969cac25e2d38d71872efe6c8226029e42bb59 installed and the exception is no longer thrown